# Override Manifest file using xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, overriding, runtime, android-manifest

Is there any possibility of the overriding manifest with a view to set at run time after the user logs in?

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml is generated as part of the build process, and the XML found within Properties/AndroidManifest.xml is merged with XML that is generated from custom attributes. What does `overriding manifest with a view` mean? Could you provide more details?

Comment: How to change the property in the Android Manifest file atruntime?. For example, I have UsesCleartextTraffic property, based on the user UsesCleartextTraffic property need to change in Manifest.xml. How to do that?

Comment: Could you provide more details of the UsesCleartextTraffic property?

Comment: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" it is android manifest property. It is used to permit the Cleartext HTTP traffic. I want to change property at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You could add it in your App.xaml.cs.

```
[Application(UsesCleartextTraffic =true)]
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page2());
    }
 }
```